# Schema table for multi-integration tokens

Tags: database, mysql

I'm designing a schema table that will manage the auth tokens for integrations // app with social networks.

At the moment only for Twitter and Facebook.

I'm thinking in this mode

```
id  social   tw_token   tw_token_auth   tw_secret   tw_secret_key   fb_token  fb_secret
1    twitter   aaa         bbbb           cccc        dddd            NULL       NULL
2    facebook   NULL        NULL          NULL         NULL            AAA1      bbb3
```

I don't like that many NULL, but for a so-simple-schema I would not realize a different table for social networks.

How to perform this better than I'm doing now?

Comment: "I'm designing a schema table" - that's exactly the failure. You need *multiple* tables (at least one for the social networks and one for the data you want to associate with the network), and the records should be connected by referential keys. I strongly recommend to google for a tutorial on database normalization and work yourself through one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you plan to have a table with a record for each social media account, and *one column for each piece of authentication data for each site*.

That last part is horribly bad. A schema that has to be changed (by adding columns) whenever a new record is inserted is a really, really bad idea. Either username/password/token or whatever you are using fulfill comparable purposes on different sites. Then they should be in the same column, not in a special-purpose site-specific column. Or they are fundamentally different. Then they need different columns, but it should be the same column for every site that also uses this information. Sites that don't use this particular mechanism can have `NULL` there. But altogether, there is no reason why you should have more columns than the number of authentication items that the most complex supported site uses.

Comment: I'm right with you, this is terrible. But you know that every social networks use his differents api-key mode to integrate them // creating an app. For this i did think to that schema. Maybe I could serialize that tokens and save in a text field, just thinking now...

Comment: If you need to store different pieces of information *and retrieve and use them under different names per site*, then you need to treat the credential pieces as individual entities and have a separate table for them, with columns like "SITE_ID", "CRED_API_NAME" and "CRED_VALUE". In other words, the multiplying column names in the example scheme should really be *values* in the CRED_API_NAME column of a separate table.

Comment: Assume that you later want to add some service whose authentication system is not token based. How to deal nicely with this? Should we from the beginning have a “auth methode” in the table, so that we can later add different semantics to the auth token?

Comment: For the sake variety, perhaps someone could recommend a more appropriate schema or method?